# Android Have View Block/Swallow Click Event

Tags: android

I have a view on top of another view. The bottom view is supposed to fire a callback when clicked. The top view is not supposed to fire any callback when clicked.

The problem I am facing is that when there is a click on the top view, the bottom view fires its callback. I want to prevent this.

I've read a number of posts on disabling clicks and they all suggest the same thing:

`view.setEnabled(false);`

and

`view.setClickable(false);`

Neither of these prevent the top view from swallowing/blocking the click event.

Do you know how I can have a view prevent passing clicks through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little hacky but the best solution I came up with was adding an empty onClickListener to swallow the event.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // HACK disables click through events by swallowing click
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what you are trying to do without an example.

But if you want to disable click for a particular view & you don't have any click functionality for this view, then try

view.setOnClickListener(null);

Also, did you try view.setFocusable(false); ??

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm not sure how an example will help. Its literally 1 view on top of another.